# I need to remove an image from the stage when I drop it onto the trash can image in AS3

Tags: image, actionscript-3

I need to remove the image from the stage whenever I drag and drop "into" the trash can. I have been looking at this forever and really cant seem to find a solution.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        import mx.controls.Image;

        //array of movies
        public var myArray:Array = ["batman.jpg","cabin.jpg","christmasVacation.jpg"];

        //init function
        public function init():void{

            var trashImage:Image = new Image();

            //set trash img
            trashImage.source = "asset/trash.jpg";

            //adds img to stage
            trashGrp.addElement(trashImage);

            //loops 4 times
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

                var arrayEntry:String = myArray[i];

                //makes new image
                var newImage:Image = new Image();

                //sets the image source for each image
                newImage.source = "asset/" + arrayEntry;

                //adds the image to the stage
                grpMovies.addElement(newImage);

                //set drag/drop
                newImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe);
                newImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe); 
            }
        }

        //dragMe function
        public function dragMe(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Get the Image that saw the mouse-down.
            var img:Image = Image(e.currentTarget);
            // Use the built-in method to start dragging.
            img.startDrag();
        }

        //dropMe function
        public function dropMe(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Get the Image that saw the mouse-up.
            var img:Image = Image(e.currentTarget);
            // Use the built-in method to stop dragging.
            img.stopDrag();

                            -**this is where my issue is. I cant get it to remove it when the image is hit**

            if (trashGrp.hitTestObject(img)) {
                grpMovies.removeElement(img);
            }

        }


    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TileGroup id="grpMovies" columnWidth="225" rowHeight="225" requestedRowCount="1"
             paddingTop="20"/>
<s:HGroup id= "trashGrp" x="950" y="20"/>


</s:Application>
```

Comment: Does `grpMovies.removeElement(img)` get executed?

Comment: No, that's what I cant figure out. I feel like it should but it doesn't. The condition in the if statement isn't being satisfied for some reason I think

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following code, I think it does what you want. I modified the event handler to be attached to the main container, so that it gets triggered properly when you release the mouse button on the trash can.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
           creationComplete="init()">

<fx:Declarations>
<!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[


    import mx.controls.Image;

    //array of movies
    public var myArray:Array = ["batman.jpg","cabin.jpg","christmasVacation.jpg"];
    private var _draggedImage:Image;

    //init function
    public function init():void{

        var trashImage:Image = new Image();

        //set trash img
        trashImage.source = "assets/trash.png";
        trashImage.mouseEnabled = false;
        trashImage.mouseChildren = false;
        //adds img to stage
        trashGrp.addElement(trashImage);

        //loops 4 times
        for(var i:Number = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){

            var arrayEntry:String = myArray[i];

            //makes new image
            var newImage:Image = new Image();

            //sets the image source for each image
            newImage.source = "assets/"+arrayEntry;

            //adds the image to the stage
            grpMovies.addElement(newImage);

            //set drag/drop
            newImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe);

        }
    }

    //dragMe function
    public function dragMe(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // Get the Image that saw the mouse-down.
        var img:Image = Image(e.currentTarget);
        // Use the built-in method to start dragging.
        img.startDrag();
        _draggedImage = img;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe); 
    }

    //dropMe function
    public function dropMe(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        _draggedImage.stopDrag();
        this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe);


        if (trashGrp.hitTestObject(_draggedImage)) {
            grpMovies.removeElement(_draggedImage);
            _draggedImage = null;
        }

    }


]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:TileGroup id="grpMovies" columnWidth="225" rowHeight="225" requestedRowCount="1"
            paddingTop="20"/>
<s:HGroup id= "trashGrp" x="950" y="20"/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works perfectly. So what I had was it was just handling it inside a certain function? Not the whole application?

Comment: What you had was trying to detect the mouse up event on the image that was being dragged, when the mouse was release over the trash can the event was never fired so it wasn't deleting the image.